# Connect dojo button inside a TooltipDialog

Tags: javascript, dojo, dom-events, dijit.form

I've a problem with `dojo.connect` when i try to connect a `dijit button` to his `'onclick'` method if the button is part of a `TooltipDialog` content.

This code doesn't give me errors, but it seems not to connect the event (so if I click at the button nothing happens).

```
dialog = new dijit.TooltipDialog({
            id: dialogPrefix + dialogId,
            content: content
        });
if (closeOnBlur) {
    // stuff
} else {
    dialog.setContent('<div class="closePopupWrapper"><button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button" id="closePopup_' + dialogId + '" >X</button></div>' + dialog.content);
    dialog.getChildren().forEach(function(w) {
        if (w.id == 'closePopup_' + dialogId) {
        //------------THIS CONNECT DOESN'T WORK
        dojo.connect(
            w,
            "onclick",
            function(e) {
                if (this.open) {
                    dojo.enabu.main.animatedpopup.close(this);
                }
        });  
        //-----------------------------------
}
```

debugging, i can see that `w` is the correct dijit button that i need to connect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need proper case on the event name, and that should be it:

```
dojo.connect(w, "onClick" ....
```

For regular DOM nodes, like a , the case doesn't matter. But since a dijit Button's click event is just a javascript function in the Button class, proper case is required.